# How do I read/write App.config settings with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, app-config

I'd like to use PowerShell as part of our automated build process to update an App.config file while deploying into our test environment. How can I do this?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Given this sample App.config: C:\Sample\App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="dbConnectionString" 
             connectionString="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True"/>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

The following script, C:\Sample\Script.ps1, will read and write a setting:

```
# get the directory of this script file
$currentDirectory = [IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)
# get the full path and file name of the App.config file in the same directory as this script
$appConfigFile = [IO.Path]::Combine($currentDirectory, 'App.config')
# initialize the xml object
$appConfig = New-Object XML
# load the config file as an xml object
$appConfig.Load($appConfigFile)
# iterate over the settings
foreach($connectionString in $appConfig.configuration.connectionStrings.add)
{
    # write the name to the console
    'name: ' + $connectionString.name
    # write the connection string to the console
    'connectionString: ' + $connectionString.connectionString
    # change the connection string
    $connectionString.connectionString = 'Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=True'
}
# save the updated config file
$appConfig.Save($appConfigFile)
```

Execute the script:

```
PS C:\Sample> .\Script.ps1
```

Output:

```
name: dbConnectionString  
connectionString: Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True
```

Updated C:\Sample\App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="dbConnectionString" 
         connectionString="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=True" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 35):

The code can be much more shorter (based on Robin's app.config):

```
$appConfig = [xml](cat D:\temp\App.config)
$appConfig.configuration.connectionStrings.add | foreach {
    $_.connectionString = "your connection string"
}

$appConfig.Save("D:\temp\App.config")
```

Comment: Cool, thanks for the tip. I didn't realize I could use that syntax.

Comment: If we are striving for short, foreach should be written as %.

Comment: @Shay Levy is it possible to update <appSettings> in config file ?
seams like <appSettings> <add key="IsFirstRun" value="False" />  </appSettings>
i need to update this value on each deployemnet .can you please help me