# Dynamic SignalR hubconnection url in Azure worker role

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr, azure-worker-roles, signalr.client

I currently have a worker role that is a SignalR .NET client. It connects to the SignalR hub, which is in the web role, like this:

```
 var connection = new HubConnection("http://localhost/");
 IHubProxy proxy = connection.CreateHubProxy("MyHub");
 connection.Start().Wait();
```

This works when run locally, but how would I go about getting the url dynamically so that it works on a development or staging server.

Answer (score 0):

1. This should help to update app.config from power shell

[How do I read/write App.config settings with PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871549/how-do-i-read-write-app-config-settings-with-powershell)

2. If you don't have write access to app.config this Updates sep app.config file:

[Update app.config system.net setting at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980440/update-app-config-system-net-setting-at-runtime)