# Update Build number in App config xml file on build pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a build pipeline in Azure DevOps, I need to update the build number in my **apconfig exe** file that will be `$(Build.BuildNumber)`.

I just tried this way:

Adding a variable **name** = `BuildNumber` **value** = `$(Build.BuildNumber)`.

And in my apconfig.exe file have a key same like `<add key="BuildNumber" value="1812201901" />`.

Why I have tried like this way: thinking like it will update in the config file if variable name match with the key.

But it is not working. can anyone please help? I have just started in CI/CD.

Comment: have you seen this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops#xmltransform?

Comment: Ya but i need to include the build number on build pipline trigger time. is that possible?

Comment: Agree with Shayki Abramczyk, The extension should be the directly way to resolve this issue, use the powershell scripts, you could search in the web, like:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871549/how-do-i-read-write-app-config-settings-with-powershell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Update Build number in App config xml file on build pipeline

Just like the Shayki said, using the [Replace Tokens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) extension should be the directly way to resolve this issue.

But since you need to request to get this extension, as workaround, you could also use power shell scripts to resolve this issue, you can check below my test powershell scripts:

```
$currentDirectory = [IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)

$appConfigFile = [IO.Path]::Combine($currentDirectory, 'App.config')

$appConfig = New-Object XML

$appConfig.Load($appConfigFile)

foreach($BuildNumber in $appConfig.configuration.add)
{
    'name: ' + $BuildNumber.name
    'BuildNumber: ' + $BuildNumber.value
    $BuildNumber.value = '123456789'
}
$appConfig.Save($appConfigFile)
```

As result, the `app.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <add key="BuildNumber" value="123456789" />
</configuration>
```

Note: Set the powershell scripts at the same folder of the `app.config` file.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Replace Tokens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) extension and in the apconfig.exe file put this:

```
<add key="BuildNumber" value="__BuildNumber__" />
```

Configure the task to search variables with `__` prefix and suffix:

[image]

Now the value will be replaced with the value of the BuildNumber variable you configured (equal to `Build.BuildNumber`).

Comment: i  have added a request to get this extension . tanks for the solution :)

Comment: You're welcome :) I hope the request will be accepted :) BTW - you can also write a small PowerShell script that do the same.

Comment: can you please give me the script :)
sorry i have no more experience in CI/CD